# Magento 2.3.X: GraphQL does not reflect catalog rule discounts

Tags: magento2.3, discount, magento2.3.2, catalog-rules, graphql

I'm using Magento 2.3.2. I've successfully completed all cart-related tasks (create cart, add a product, select shipping& payment methods, and place the order) using GraphQL.

GraphQL seems not to include the product real final price after applying the catalog rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the XML configuration files found in `vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/etc/webapi_rest/*.xml` into a custom module in the `etc/graphql` area appears to resolve this issue.

See this article for full details: https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/09/magento-2-3-fix-graphql-does-not-reflect-catalog-rule-discounts/

Comment: Thank you, btw I've fallback to the Rest API :)